# Get text and image to float next to each other

Tags: html, css

[image: view my picture]

As shown with the yellow circle and arrow, I want the text in the middle (red square), next to the image. Is it possible, if yes, how?

```css
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.contact{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body id="home">
  
      
<br><br><br><br><br> 
         <div class="row">
             <div class="contact">
     <h1>creative consultant </h1>
    <h3>& service designer</h3>
     <br><p>catch me at +(45)xx xx xx xx
    <br> or caroline@live.dk</p></div>
  <div class="column">
      <img src="me_outline.svg" alt="outline.me" style="width:100%">
  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Output]

```css
    .column {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px;

    }
    .row{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        transform: translate(50% ,50%);
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<body id="home">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://place-hold.it/500x500" alt="outline.me">
    </div>         
    <div class="row">
        <div class="contact">
            <h1>creative consultant </h1>
            <h3>& service designer</h3>
            <br><p>catch me at +(45)xx xx xx xx
            <br> or caroline@live.dk</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mind adding an explanation as to what your code does?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of the elements, and use Flexbox:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contact {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body id="home">


  <br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="outline.me" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <h1>creative consultant </h1>
      <h3>& service designer</h3>
      <br>
      <p>catch me at +(45)xx xx xx xx
        <br> or caroline@live.dk</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```